# Simple threads don't execute exactly parallely

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable

I'm starting ten threads to update ten progress bars.
It should take five seconds to complete the bars.
When starting just one thread, it completes in five seconds.
When starting all ten threads, they update asynchronously and they complete in more than five seconds.
Is it possible to achieve this task in a more efficient way so that all ten progress bars complete in five seconds?

Here's MainActivity.java

```
package com.google.example;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<ProgressBar> bars = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            int id = getResources().getIdentifier("b" + (i+1), "id", getPackageName());
            bars.add((ProgressBar) findViewById(id));
        }

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                int num = 10;

                for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
                    MyRunnable runnable = new MyRunnable(bars.get(i));
                    Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
                    thread.start();
                }

            }
        });

    }

    class MyRunnable implements Runnable{

        ProgressBar bar;

        MyRunnable(ProgressBar b){
            bar = b;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int progress = 0;
            long previous = 0;

            while(progress < 100) {
                long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if (time != previous && time % 50 == 0) {
                    progress++;
                    bar.setProgress(progress);
                    previous = time;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And here's activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/b4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/b5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/b6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/b7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/b8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/b9"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/b10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the output when starting one thread only
[image]

Here's when starting all together
[image]

EDIT: As suggested by @greeble31 I solved the problem by changing MyRunnable to

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable{

        ProgressBar bar;

        MyRunnable(ProgressBar b){
            bar = b;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int progress = 0;
            long hack = System.currentTimeMillis();

            while(progress < 100) {
                progress = (int) ((System.currentTimeMillis() - hack) / 50);
                bar.setProgress(progress);
            }

        }
}
```

This is what it looks like now. 
[image]

Comment: `MyRunnable.run` is nonsense: not only is it spinning, but what if it misses a particular multiple-of-50 millisecond?  If your actual work is compute-bound, slowdown from too many threads is inevitable.  If it’s not, you just need to produce the progress output in a less wasteful fashion.

Comment: "Is it possible ... all ten progress bars complete in five seconds?"  - It is possible if your device has at least 10 processors (note that often processors are named "cores").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DavisHerring mentioned in a comment, this is (almost entirely) due to missed millis in `MyRunnable.run()`. Your code assumes that the loop will "see" perfectly sequential return values from `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

You might have reasoned that since the loop runs full-speed, it will no doubt be able to call `System.currentTimeMillis()` many times each millisecond, and therefor it is unlikely any will be missed. But then, you have more threads than you have cores, so clearly some threads must spend part of their time preempted.

Besides, on any preemptive multi-tasking operating system, there is no guarantee that any particular thread will be executing at any particular time.

So, if a given thread ceases executing for a brief moment, it could easily miss a multiple of 50. For example, one of the threads could "see" the following return values from `System.currentTimeMillis()`:

```
1546215544594
1546215544594
1546215544594
1546215544594   <-- thread is unscheduled here, causing a 23ms gap
1546215544617
1546215544617
1546215544617
1546215544617
```

**SUGGESTED FIX**

Instead of trying to catch each milli, take a time hack at the beginning. Then just make `progress` equal to (elapsed time) / 50:

```
progress = (int) ((System.currentTimeMillis() - hack) / 50);
bar.setProgress(progress);
```

As an aside: `System.currentTimeMillis()` is not guaranteed to return a monotonically increasing result (see `System.uptimeTimeMillis()` for an alternative), but for your particular problem, that's probably not as big of an issue.

Comment: You're a lifesaver. I did not consider I'd lose milliseconds with multi-threading. When I tried with a single thread, the log printed the same value for 6-7 times.

Answer (score 0):

Since 1 thread takes 5 seconds and I doubt your device has 10 cores (probably 2 of 4 since this appears to be a tablet), you’re not going to get all 10 to complete in 5 seconds. If you do as many threads / bars as you have cores, it should do it in about 5 seconds. If you use more threads than you have cores, the threads will definitely have to share cores to get the work done and it’ll take a little longer (but still much less than it would have been synchronously). Even with matching your thread count to cores, there’s no guarantee that you can have uninterrupted access to all of them for your app — there’s still a whole OS and background tasks going on that need to run.

Since 1 thread takes 5 seconds, then 10 synchronously would take 50 seconds. 6-7 seconds over 10 threads is pretty good.

Comment: AFAIK, even with exactly as many thread as cores, it's still not guaranteed (at all) that the OS's scheduler will divide this work among all cores. Especially since there's already a ton of things ran by Android. I couldn't find any resource that says that the OS is guaranteed to spread the work equally on all cores

Comment: @ArthurAttout I was just thinking about that. You’re right, with so many other tasks going on, there’s no guarantee that you can have access to all cores for the duration of the progress bars.

Comment: @ArthurAttout In fact its likely not to, as there's good reasons to prefer to run threads from the same app on the same cores.  For example, if you don't switch to a new process you don't need to clear out the TLB.  Until it sees that a process is non-interactive (its CPU bound) it will prefer to schedule it on the same core as other threads from that app to avoid those costs.  More real world workloads than this bad code example, most threads end up spending most of their time waiting on IO or yielding until signaled, so they can share a core easily.